# Google+ API Person.isPlusUser() always returning false for visible people for the current logged in user

Tags: android, google-plus

I've recently started to work with the Google+ API for Android and come along a somewhat weird behavior.

Whenever I call

```
PlusClient.loadVisiblePeople()
```

The `Person` objects returned will always return `false` whenever I call `Person.isPlusUser()`

The documentation states

> isPlusUser()
>
> ```
>  Whether this user has signed up for Google+.
> ```

I can see that if I call the method on the current user logged in it's returning `true`.

Does anyone know if this is the correct behavior for this call? If so, does this mean, that whatever visible people that are returned from the `loadVisiblePeople()` method is a Google+ user? If so, why doesn't the method just return `true`?

Is this info not public visible perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahh - and if I had just read the documentation a little better I would've found out why it's false all the time ;-)

When looking at the `PlusClient.loadVisiblePeople()` [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/plus/PlusClient.html#loadVisiblePeople%28com.google.android.gms.plus.PlusClient.OnPeopleLoadedListener,%20java.lang.String%29) it states:

> Each Person will contain the id, displayName, image, objectType, and
>   url fields populated. To retrieve additional profile data, use the
>   loadPeople(PlusClient.OnPeopleLoadedListener, String...) method.

So the isPlusUser is never filled and so defaults back to `false` of course :-)

So I need to fetch the users `ids` and call the `loadPeople()` method passing all the `ids` to get the rest of the data - not so comprehensive...